# Friend function cannot access private member variable

Tags: c++, friend, pure-virtual

I'm having two classes, `PlayerCharacter` and `Ability`. The `Ability` class has an pure virtual function which I declare as a `friend` to `PlayerCharacter`. However, I seem to be unable to access the private members within the `friend` declared function. Is it something I overlook?

I have attemped to declare the child function rather than the virtual one as the friend function, but to no effect.

**player_chracter.h :**

```
#include "ability.h"

class PlayerCharacter : public Character {
private:
    // Friend function
    friend bool Ability::ExecuteAbility(PlayerCharacter& in_player);

    // This doesn't work either
    //friend bool Dash::ExecuteAbility(PlayerCharacter& in_player);

    // Private variable
    float top_speed_;
}
```

**ability.h :**

```
//Forward declaration
class PlayerCharacter;

class Ability {
public:
    Ability();
    ~Ability();
    virtual bool ExecuteAbility(PlayerCharacter& in_player) = 0;
};
//---------------------------------------------------------
class Dash : public Ability {
public:
    Dash();
    ~Dash();
    bool ExecuteAbility(PlayerCharacter& in_player);
};
```

**ability.cpp :**

```
#include "ability.h"
#include "player_character.h"   //Follow through on forward declaraction

bool Dash::ExecuteAbility(PlayerCharacter& in_player) {
    float example = in_player.top_speed_;
}
```

In the code above, why cannot I access `top_speed_` and put it in the `float example` variable?

Comment: Could you add the error messages in both cases please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [`[class.friend]/10`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.friend#10), friendship is not inherited. 
A derived class does not automatically become a friend of a class just because its parent class is a friend of that class.

The reason why the below also does not work either is probably because `Dash` is not defined before the function `ExecuteAbility` is defined.

```
friend bool Dash::ExecuteAbility(PlayerCharacter& in_player);
```

However, with the **proper order** of definitions it will work. See [DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/P1384j).

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be the case. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Notes):

> Friendship is not transitive (a friend of your friend is not your friend)
>
> Friendship is not inherited (your friend's children are not your friends)

Even if `Dash::ExecuteAbility` overrides a `friend` function from its base class, it does not benefit from it. You'll have to rethink your design.

Comment: Hi Quentin. How do you explain `// This doesn't work either //friend bool Dash::ExecuteAbility(PlayerCharacter& in_player);` ?

Comment: @YSC The question lacks a copy of the error (did I answer too soon? Possibly.) but I suspect it's just a case of `Dash` not being defined beforehand.